# Need help making a DRY method on ObjectAnimator

Tags: java, android

Could someone suggest an efficient way to follow a DRY principle on this code? I use it so much.. Would I need to perform 2 separate methods? One that returns an image, then one that returns a textview? Thanks!

```
 mInspireMeImg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            if (mInspireMeBOOL) {

                mInspireMeImgAnimation = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(mInspireMeImg, "translationY", +300);

                mInspireMeTxtAnimation = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(mInspireMeTxt, "translationY", +300);


                Log.w(tag, "DOWN Coordinates: " + mInspireMeImg.getY() + " Txt: " + mInspireMeTxt.getY());


                mInspireMeImgAnimation.setDuration(1000);
                mInspireMeTxtAnimation.setDuration(1000);

                mInspireMeImgAnimation.start();
                mInspireMeTxtAnimation.start();

                mInspireMeBOOL = false;
            } else {



                mInspireMeBOOL = true;
                mInspireMeImgAnimation = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(mInspireMeImg, "translationY", -200);
                mInspireMeTxtAnimation = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(mInspireMeTxt, "translationY", -200);

                Log.w(tag, "UP Coordinates: " + mInspireMeImg.getY() + "Txt: " + mInspireMeTxt.getY());

                mInspireMeImgAnimation.setDuration(1000);
                mInspireMeTxtAnimation.setDuration(1000);

                mInspireMeImgAnimation.start();

                mInspireMeTxtAnimation.start();

            }

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

```
private static void translateView(View view, int translationY)
{
    ObjectAnimator animator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view, "translationY", translationY);
    animator.setDuration(1000);
    animator.start();
}
```

Then call it with `mInspireMeImgAnimation`, `300`, &c.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answer above you can move these lines :

```
Log.w(tag, "DOWN Coordinates: " + mInspireMeImg.getY() + " Txt: " + mInspireMeTxt.getY());


mInspireMeImgAnimation.setDuration(1000);
mInspireMeTxtAnimation.setDuration(1000);

mInspireMeImgAnimation.start();
mInspireMeTxtAnimation.start();
```

Out of the if statement as they are the same either way.